# Tried to Add Library, but with Gradlew Clean: Build Fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm new to Android Studio and intelliJ. I'm trying to add a library. I put the .jar in the libs folder, and added

```
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar', 'libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
```

to build.gradle. And I tried navigating in terminal to my project folder and running
    gradlew clean
but I got:

```
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/myproject/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'myproject']
Evaluating root project 'myproject' using build file '/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/myproject/build.gradle'.
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
org.gradle.listener.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:90)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:465)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:76)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGroovyObjectGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy:1211)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$resolveDependencyForConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencies(BasePlugin.groovy:1164)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$resolveDependencies.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.doCreateAndroidTasks(AppPlugin.groovy:196)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:242)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:190)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:81)
... 41 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/myproject/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

But I thought I set the paths correctly; the project runs find until I try to use the added library (the app crashes, of course). Here's the relevant part of my .profile

```
export ANDROID_SDK="<Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools>"
export ANDROID_NDK="<Downloads/android-ndk-r8b>"
export ANDROID_HOME="<Downloads/android-sdk-macosx>"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: changed path as suggested in answer below. Problem persists. More error info added as requested.

Comment: are u sure android studio is the right IDE? after all it still is on beta 0.1.1

Comment: I guess I'll crawl back to Eclipse and beg forgiveness.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally fixed it. Altering the `ANDROID_HOME` didn't work. Instead I created a **local.properities** file in my project's directory and added

`sdk.dir=/Users/myname/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx`  --- my path to the android sdk

then I could `gradlew clean`. Now AS can find my library and my app works.

Comment: I had the same problem and I compared the problematic android project to one that worked. Both had all settings/configuration files identical except that file. It is worth to mention that, that file is created automatically from Android Studio (when you create a new project), but when you share the code in a repository (i.e. github) it's better to ignore such files but expect that others will somehow will create it on their own...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like ANDROID_HOME is set right. You need to set it to wherever your SDK resides (it would appear to be Downloads/android-sdks).

Comment: I tried that path, and a bunch of others, with the same result. I think I'm going to stick with Eclipse until Android Studio matures some.

Comment: It was a NoClassDefFound error for my jsoup library when I tried to use a method from that library.